# Woocommerce fixed price by amount of specific products in cart

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am building a bookstore shop in woocommerce well I need to add 3 books in 100 or 4 in 100, I didn't find any plugin that I capable to do it, any way or thoughts on how can I make it happen (will be happy to get also php code)

for example:
If a customer select three books i need the subtotal to be 100 if he orders 4 books it will cost 120 so in the product page he will see the regular price while in the cart the subtotal will be change, so lets say he has 6 books in the cart the price will be 120 for the first 4 books and then the normal prices will be added

Comment: What does mean *" I need to add 3 books in 100 or 4 in 100"*? please try to clarify.

Comment: Well if a customer select three books i need the subtotal to be 100 if he orders 4 books it will cost 120 so in the product page he will see the regular price while in the cart the subtotal will be change, so lets say he have 6 books in cart the price will be 120 for the first 4 books and then the normal prices will be added

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please can you review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide?

You need to *edit your question* and add in what you have tried so far and the problems you've got. Just adding this information as a comment will not be good enough.

Comment: HI, @webli, you want to give discount?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you want to give discount to your customers right, if max item reach.

woo-commerce hook, you can use for your solution :

> woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees

```
if( $cart->cart_contents_count < 6 ){
return;
}
```

Here, you can find the help:

[Woocommerce fixed price by amount of specific products in cart](https://therichpost.com/woocommerce-bulk-quantity-discount-hook)